# Nginx reverse proxy 502 bad gateway

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Hello i want to use nginx reverse proxy url parameters but not working.

```
location /redirect {
 proxy_pass $arg_url;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_buffer_size 16k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 24k;
proxy_buffers 64 4k;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
```

I try login my website:

http://example.com/redirect?url=http://google.com

Result 502 Bad Gateway

Why can't i use

Comment: `Why can't you use` what? What are you looking for?

Comment: @Andromeda http://example.com/redirect?url=http://google.com

When I enter the link, I want it to log in to the url parameter I specified, and while doing this, I need to send referer and origin information.